# What is different on the server versions of 11.10 and 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, 11.10, server

I was wondering if it's worth to upgrade to 11.10 if I have 10.04 as a server.

- What do I notice as different if I have a server? (not the GUI as for the desktop)
- Is there a list of stuff that is new/improved for the server
  releases?
- What packages are different that I will notice as a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ubuntu Release Notes wiki page includes a [section for Ubuntu Server](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server).  By looking through the release notes for the last 3 releases ([Maverick](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server_Edition), [Natty](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server), and [Oneiric](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server)) you can get a good list of the things that have changed.

To name just a few of the new features since 10.04:

- Platform preview available for ARM architecture
- Ubuntu Server 11.10 includes a tech preview of [Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/)
- Improved power consumption and system monitoring with PowerNap 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You should note that you can't upgrade directly from LTS (long term support) release to nonLTS release that is not a next release, you'll be needing to upgrade first to 10.10, then 11.04 and then to 11.10. However you'll be able to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 directly, because 12.04 is also a LTS. 
Generally you'll get newer versions of packages. But if you're satisfied how 10.04 works and don't have explicit need for example newer version of php/apache/mysql you'll be fine and perhaps should wait for 12.04. I also have 10.04 on my server and am not thinking of upgrading any time soon.

Comment: I don't care about the mess, I could make a fresh install anyway! I  want to know what packages are different!

Comment: @Alvar all the packages that have never stable versions are upgraded on newer versions of Ubuntu. Do these upgraded packages have any advantages for your usage of the system is another question. You should look at release changes of packages that you're interested in.

Comment: This doesn't even answer my question! ...

Answer (score 0):

[Release Notes](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes) contains the list of all release notes for recent versions of Ubuntu, on each release
notes page there is a section devoted to server improvements: [Ubuntu 11.10 Server Improvements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server)

Although unless there is a new feature you really need or want you should rather upgrade from LTS to LTS for the improved stability.

Comment: yes the LTS have long time support, which isn't great if the server is a laptop! :)